# list view selection mode none in windows form applications

Tags: c#, winforms

i am working on windows form application ..i have a list view.
in the list view some time i will select some row then i will click add button .that time selected rows will add to list view.

after that i want to make my `listview selection mode none` so i wrote code like this

```
List_Item.Select = Nothing ..
```

but this code throwing error? how i can make my list view selection mode none?
any help is very appreciable.thanks in advance

Comment: First thing first, you can not modify a collection while enumerating it. Second your error is pretty clear, nothing is selected for index at 0...

Comment: sir can i ask one doubt?

Comment: Yes you can... what you want?

Comment: in list box i will select one row and i will click add button.that time that same row will add to list box.after that i want remove cursor positon from list box

Comment: i want to make listbox selectionmode none? how

Comment: sir not list box ,,i want to make list view selection mode none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop every item and set the selected field to false

```
 For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.List_Item.Items
     item.Selected = false       
 Next
```